# grab two values from command output in a for loop

Tags: bash

I'm trying to loop through all of the repositories on our satellite servers and list the number of rpms in each.  I need the repository ID and NAME which I can get from

```
hammer --csv repository list | grep -v 'Id,Name' | cut -d, -f1,2`
```

Given ID and NAME, I can get the number of packages and print out:

```
SUM=$(hammer repository info --id ${ID} | grep Packages | awk '{ print $2 }');
echo "In repository, ${NAME}, there are ${SUM} packages."
```

I just can't figure out how to put that in a loop.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Pipe the output of the command to a `while read sum name` loop.

Comment: Or just do it all in awk.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```bash
hammer --csv repository list | grep -v 'Id,Name' | while IFS=, read -r ID NAME; do
  SUM=$(hammer repository info --id ${ID} | grep Packages | awk '{ print $2 }')
  echo "In repository, ${NAME}, there are ${SUM} packages."
done
```

Comment: Could the pipe to `grep Packages` be replaced with a pipe to `awk /Packages/ { print $2 }'?

Comment: Yes, it would do the same.